# When should I use Async.AwaitIAsyncResult instead of Async.AwaitTask to await a Task?

Tags: f#, async-await, task, f#-async

I want to await a `Task<int>` returned by Entity Framework Core when saving changes with the following call: `myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync true`

I found at least 3 different ways of achieving that but I am not really sure which one is the best considering that I don't really care about the `int` result part in `Task<int>`, at the end of the day I just wanna to await.

Using `Async.AwaitIAsyncResult` and then `Async.AwaitIgnore` to ignore the `Task<bool>`:

```ml
async {
    do! myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync true
    |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
    |> Async.AwaitIgnore
}
```

Upcasting the `Task<int>` to `Task` and then just awaiting that `Task` with `Async.AwaitTask`:

```ml
async {
    do! myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync true
    :> Task
    |> Async.AwaitTask
}
```

Awaiting `Task<int>` with `Async.AwaitTask` and ignoring the result with `Async.Ignore`

```ml
async {
    do! myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync true
    |> Async.AwaitTask
    |> Async.Ignore
}
```

`AwaitIAsyncResult` seems more relevant if I wanted to fetch a boolean in case of error while awaiting the task (and / or I wanted to have some control over the execution with a timeout): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.awaitiasyncresult-method-%5Bfsharp%5D?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. I am also suspecting that this is the right if I wanted to avoid having an exception thrown to my face in case of something going wrong while awaiting and instead fetch a boolean.

Which leaves then the two other solutions, I would say that the last one translates better my intent of not caring about the `int` of `Task<int>` / `Async<int>`.

However I am not too sure, can someone can validate or invalidate my thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interface `IAsyncResult` is a legacy from the very early days of async on .NET (remember `FileStream.BeginRead`/`FileStream.EndRead`), so it's used only when interop with legacy APIs.

The fact that `Async.AwaitIAsyncResult` returns `Async<bool>` does not mean that it handles exceptions in any way, in fact it does not.

So with `Async.AwaitIAsyncResult` out of the way, I'll say that your third example

```
async {
    do! myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync true
    |> Async.AwaitTask
    |> Async.Ignore
}
```

is the way to go, since the intent is explicit.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see how your example would compile so I hope I'm not missing something here.

I think this is how I'd tackle it:

```ml
open FSharp.Control.Tasks.V2 // From nuget package Taskbuilder.fs

let someExampleAsync (thing: bool) : Threading.Tasks.Task<int> = 
    task {
        printfn "this got called"
        return 1
    }

let saveChanges() : Async<int> = someExampleAsync true |> Async.AwaitTask

// await once
saveChanges() |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore

// await a few times
let repeatIt = 
    async {
        let! awaitOnce = saveChanges()
        let! awaitAgain = saveChanges()
        let! awaitAndAgain = saveChanges()
        return "all done"
    }

repeatIt |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
```

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner.